# Include multiple pages on frontpage Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, templates

I've got (probably) a silly question. I want to create a single-page website on Wordpress.
I would like to achieve somthing equivalent to PHP code like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="home">
    <?php include 'home.php';?>
  </div>

  <div id="about-us">
   <?php include 'about-us.php';?>
  </div>
</body>
```

What I want is to include posts/pages with specific IDs created in the backend of Wordpress.

How can I achieve this using the Loop? Or there's another way to do this? I want to print pages as well as blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

If you can include any file in the theme folder using

```
require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/plugable/tiny-mce/buttons.php';
```

But it will not be logical. It would be more appropriate to use a loop. there you choose the type of post ( post, page etc. ). here example

```html
 <?php
// Define the query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <article title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="card">
   <a class="" href="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <img class="card__img" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
    <div class="up-2">
     <h3 class="card__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    </div>
   </a>
            </article>
        </div>

<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata() ?>
```

[post types](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/post-types/)

[wp query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)